# Determining the leaving group for substituted benzene in Aromatic nucleophilic substitution

Tags: reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, nucleophilic-substitution

[image]

I could figure out that After the substitution of one of the halogens, with the $\ce{-OCH3}$ group(Electron donating group), the ring would be deactivated towards nucleophilic substitution hence the second halogen won't be substituted (option  (c)).

But I'm having problem deciding between (a) and (b). (a) seems right since Cl, is indeed a better leaving group but then (b) also seems right since $\ce{NO2}$ is para to the Fluorine.
How do we determine which Halogen would be lost?

Comment: Isn’t F a better LG then Cl in context of $\ce{S_NAr}$?

Comment: SNAr can take place only at para and ortho position of a strong electron withdrawing group

Comment: @Rishi oh yes that completely ran out of my mind. Thanks!

Comment: @PrajwalTiwari You can answer your own question. Go for it!